# Floating image position looks different on every computer

Tags: css

I'm trying to position an image on my blog, but after I got it in the spot I wanted, I checked my other computer with a different sized screen and it wasn't lined up anymore. Is there a way to lock it somehow so it will look the same from every computer? Also, it is positioned right above the white box with text, is there a way to move that box down? I've tried everything.

Here is the image code:

```
<img src='http://i111.photobucket.com/albums/n144/baby_painting/banner4.png' style='position:fixed;top:105px;left:592px;z-index:999'/>
```

I'm pretty sure this is the code for the box:

```
div#sidebar{
position:fixed !important;
width: 280px;
height:390px;
background-color: {color:sidebar};
margin: 100px 0px 0px 0px;
border-right:0px dashed #B9AFB2;
border-left:0px solid #000;
padding-top:5px;
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #C9C9C9;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #C9C9C9;
}
```

The blog is at nikkidarlinggg.tumblr.com for reference

Comment: The theme is a mess, not going to lie, but what's happening is that you have the image code put in the wrong spot so it's only going to look like you want on one monitor. This is where you want to put it: `<div id="sidebar"><img src="http://i111.photobucket.com/albums/n144/baby_painting/banner4.png" style="position:absolute;top:-52px;left:8px">` Good luck.

Comment: Thanks it worked. And do you mean a mess in terms of looks, or the way it's coded? Also do you know how to move the white box down?

Comment: The coding! It looks great visually speaking. To move down the white box change the first value for `margin` in `div#sidebar` to be larger than `100px`. And I just realized you might be wanting to reposition that image you just moved? Change `top:-52px` in the inline-style if you need to move that around.

Comment: Oh hahah yeah I just found a random theme and used it. Thanks for the help! I had no idea how to move that.